# How to connect Strip-terminal-physical-device BBPOS Chipper 2X BT using ionic or cordova or Angular or Java Scrpit

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, strip

I need to connect from my Hybrid app to Strip-terminal-physical-device  BBPOS Chipper 2X BT Using IONIC Or NodeJS or cordova or Java Scrpit.

Comment: You'll want to use the official Stripe Terminal JavaScript SDK: https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/sdk/js

Comment: This is applicable for  verifone-p400 but not wireless bbpos-chipper-2x-bt.

Comment: Hey man. Have you found a solution?